# How is $ k+ 1 + \frac{1}{2}k(k+1) = \frac{1}{2}(k+1)(k+2)?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can't understand How come $ k+ 1 + \frac{1}{2}k(k+1) = \frac{1}{2}(k+1)(k+2) ?$

Comment: You could try expanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$k+ 1 + \frac{1}{2}k(k+1)$$
Take $k + 1$ common,
$$= (k+1)\left(1+\frac{k}{2}\right)$$ 
$$= (k+1)\left(\frac{2+k}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(k+1)(k+2)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $k \in \mathbb{R}$, then
$k+1 + \frac{1}{2}k(k+1) = (k+1)(1 + \frac{k}{2}) = (k+1)\frac{1}{2}(2 +k) = \frac{1}{2}(k+1)(k+2)$.